# How do I add child <li> elements to <ul> without removing current children

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

How do I iteratively add children elements to a (for example) a .

```
<ul id="my-list">
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

If I have a JS script that runs something like this several times:

```
document.getElementById('my-list').appendChild('someListItemICreated')
```

the current 2 list items are removed. How do I add new li items to the ul without losing the current list itmes?

Comment: Post your [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an element as the argument for `appendChild` and not a string. Like this:

```js
const li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerText = "Item 3";
document.getElementById("my-list").appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

A much easier and a cleaner approach that I prefer in most of cases is:

```js
document.getElementById("my-list").innerHTML += "<li>Item 3</li>";
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const c = document.createElement('li');
c.innerText = 'item 3';
document.getElementById('my-list').appendChild(c);
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific with what your code is actually doing, but I can say that someListItemICreated should not be a string, if that's what you're passing. Here's an example I made that's similar to what you're referring to that runs fine.

```
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

```
let someListItemICreated = document.createElement("li");
someListItemICreated.appendChild(document.createTextNode("item 3"));

document.getElementById("my-list").appendChild(someListItemICreated)
```

Comment: Ok, I could have sworn that I tried doing it like this and it wiped out the current list items...But I just tried it in my code and it works. Thanks!!